# Clear textarea with facebook webdriver

Tags: php, webdriver, facebook-webdriver

I'm using the PHP [facebook/webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) package to handle some web automation testing.

I have been unable to clear the content of a `<textarea>` element and have run out of options.

Given:

- a dom element `<textarea>content</textarea>`
- `$element` to be a `Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverElement` instance

I have tried calling `RemoteWebElement::clear()`:

```
// phpdoc for this method states: 
// "If [is] TEXTAREA or text INPUT element, this will clear the value"

var_dump($element->getTagName()); // string(8) "textarea"
var_dump($element->getText());    // string(7) "content"

$element->clear(); 

var_dump($element->getText());    // string(7) "content"
```

I have tried sending backspace keys:

```
var_dump($element->getTagName()); // string(8) "textarea"
var_dump($element->getText());    // string(7) "content"

for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($element->getText()); $i++) {
    $element->sendKeys(WebDriverKeys::BACKSPACE);
}

var_dump($element->getText());    // string(7) "content"
```

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To query the content of a textarea, use `$element->getAttribute('value')` instead of `$element->getText()`.

`RemoteWebElement::getText()` appears only to get the text node that was present at the time the page loaded. At least that is my best guess based on observed behaviour.

`RemoteWebElement::getAttribute('value')` gets the current content of a texarea. I did not guess at this being the correct solution due to a texarea element not having a value attribute in HTML.